# Asp.NET Core json file or data path - where to put it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am in .NET MVC, I wish to read a JSON file like so:

```
 JSON = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("companyInfo.json");
```

However I can't get a path going.  I don't care where I put the json file, so I am asking for both a recommended place to put it as well as the path string to use.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can Try to use the following with asp.net core

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

        public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
               var   JSON = System.IO.File.ReadAllText( contentRootPath + "/companyInfo.json");
            return null; 
        }
    }
```

**Update**
The `contentrootPath` will give you the base  root of your application

Something like this `ContentRoot:  C:\MyApp\` note it depends on the OS 
you can create a data folder and use `Path.Combine` to build your absolute path

But you can use the **WebRootPath**

```
string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;
```

if you want it to be served from The web root which is the root directory from which static content is served,

Comment: Seems logical, so in your example, the file is located where? In the root folder?

Comment: Looks like `IHostingEnvironment` is now Obsolete & deprecated! on Both libraries `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting`. I'm using .net 5

Comment: Use `IWebHostEnvironment` instead

Answer (score 5):

An appropriate place to put it is the `App_Data` folder inside your project root.  If this folder doesn't exist, create it.  This folder is somewhat special, in that nothing in that folder can be directly requested by a browser; it can only be accessed via code.  Getting the path to `App_Data` is fairly straightforward:

```
string filePath = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/companyInfo.json");
```

Using that path, you can open your file for reading.

You *can* use any folder you want for this, but you'll need to take steps to prevent the browser from directly requesting the file.  ASP.Net does this for you automatically for `App_Data`.

Comment: Seems logical, however "Server" needs an assembly reference or something..  I'm using .NET Core, not sure how to include "httpcontext.server"

Comment: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/302/server-mappath-equivalent-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @DevinAndresSalemi I've added Core as a tag on the question.

Comment: That makes my answer, irrelevant.  I'm going to delete it.

Comment: Thanks, since there are often differences between Core and Framework we must specify

Comment: The first code snippet in the link pasted by @fran should address this.  I'll edit my answer later, dont have the energy right now.

Comment: @Amy (nice icon btw). This answer is still present. Please can you delete it? (see your comment above)