# Timeout error in trying to access swagger.json in IHostedService through a httpclient call

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, asp.net-core-5.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I wanted to access the swagger.json file and deserialized it and store it into the cache.

I am making the async call in the `IHostedService`.

```cs
public class InitializeCacheService : IHostedService
{
    private IMemoryCache _cache;
    public static readonly string swaggerJson = "swagger.json";
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public InitializeCacheService(IMemoryCache cache, HttpClient client, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _httpClient = client;

        _cache = cache;
    }
    public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!_cache.TryGetValue(swaggerJson, out SwaggerDocumentCache cacheEntry))
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44397");

            var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("swagger/v1/swagger.json");

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            using var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            cacheEntry = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync
                <SwaggerDocumentCache>(responseStream);

            var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions()
                  .SetSlidingExpiration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

            _cache.Set(swaggerJson, cacheEntry, cacheEntryOptions);
        }
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

But the application is spinning and spinning and it is getting time out in
`var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("swagger/v1/swagger.json");`

The error it is giving is:

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

What I am missing here? What is the correct way of accessing the `swagger.json` to build a custom API playground application?

Comment: How about write an api to read the content of swagger.json and send request to this api to obtain the data?

Comment: I was stuck on reading the content of swagger.json programmatically

Comment: Thanks for reply and according to your snippet, it seems that you are sending an http request to acquire json file content from another server. I mean you can write the [reading content code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45224353) in that server program.

Comment: I tried the way you provided but that doesn't work too. it still got me to the time-out error. because the swagger.json is not physically available in any folder.

Comment: I showed my idea below and, here you said `is not physically available in any folder`, so why you try to access the file by `https://localhost:44397/swagger/v1/swagger.json` ? I'm puzzled here sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SwaggerMiddleware](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/21391c2ea7dcb407784689ad861560623169673f/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger/SwaggerMiddleware.cs#L85) handles serving OpenAPI documents. We can use that as reference to build the document ourselves.

First register `SwaggerGenerator` with DI:

```cs
// Startup.Configure
services.AddTransient<SwaggerGenerator>();
```

Then inject it inside a class, here I'm using an endpoint to serve it directly:

```cs
// Startup.Configure
app.UseEndpoints(e =>
{
    // ...
    e.MapGet("/openapi.json", context =>
    {
        // inject SwaggerGenerator
        var swaggerGenerator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SwaggerGenerator>();
        // document name is defined in Startup.ConfigureServices method inside the AddSwaggerGen call
        var doc = swaggerGenerator.GetSwagger("v1");

        // serialize the document as json
        using var writer = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var serializer = new OpenApiJsonWriter(writer);
        doc.SerializeAsV3(serializer);
        var json = writer.ToString(); // this is the openapi document
        
        // serve it as json
        context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual JSON is not necessarily a valid endpoint which may be a problem in an of itself. Have you attempted the call without the explicit file name on the endpoint route?

Comment: do you mean like this _httpClient.GetAsync("swagger/v1/swagger");?