# How to customize the swagger UI using my own custom design

Tags: c#, .net-core, swagger-ui, asp.net-core-5.0, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I wanted to customize the swagger UI using my own custom design. I have the following configuration in a startup.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews();
    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.DocumentFilter<DescriptionsDocumentFilter>();

        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "LoggerDemo", Version = "v1" });

        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);
    });
    services.AddHttpClient();
    services.AddMemoryCache();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseSwagger(o =>
        {
            o.RouteTemplate = "docs/{documentName}/docs.json";
        });

        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.RoutePrefix = "docs";
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/v1/docs.json", "Geo API");

            c.IndexStream = () => GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
            (
                GetType().Namespace + ".Resources.Swagger_Custom_index.html"
            );
        });
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Here are the steps I have followed:

- I have got a copy of the original index.html from here: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI/index.html
- Created the folder `Resources` and placed the file name `Swagger_Custom_index.html` in the Resources folder

[image]

- Implemented the following in `Configure` in startup.cs:

```cs
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.IndexStream = () => GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream
    (
        GetType().Namespace + ".Resources.Swagger_Custom_index.html"
    );
});
```

But I am struggling to access the custom HTML file, How to access the custom HTML file? What URL should I use to access those files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to embed the HTML file in the DLL with an `EmbeddedResource` directive in your `.csproj` file:

`Resources/swagger.html`

```html
<!-- replace this with the actual swagger.html -->
<h1>hello swagger</h1>
```

`.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <!-- ... -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <Content Remove="Resources\*" />
        <EmbeddedResource Include="Resources\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then you can access it with `Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`:

```cs
// Startup.Configure

app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.IndexStream = () => GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{GetType().Namespace}.Resources.swagger.html");
});
```

---

### Bonus: Generating OpenAPI Document outside Swagger:

[SwaggerMiddleware](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/21391c2ea7dcb407784689ad861560623169673f/src/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger/SwaggerMiddleware.cs#L85) handles serving OpenAPI documents. We can use that as reference to build the document ourselves.

First register `SwaggerGenerator` with DI:

```cs
// Startup.Configure
services.AddTransient<SwaggerGenerator>();
```

Then inject it inside a class, here I'm using an endpoint to serve it directly:

```cs
// Startup.Configure
app.UseEndpoints(e =>
{
    // ...
    e.MapGet("/openapi.json", context =>
    {
        // inject SwaggerGenerator
        var swaggerGenerator = context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<SwaggerGenerator>();
        // document name is defined in Startup.ConfigureServices method inside the AddSwaggerGen call
        var doc = swaggerGenerator.GetSwagger("v1");

        // serialize the document as json
        using var writer = new StringWriter(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        var serializer = new OpenApiJsonWriter(writer);
        doc.SerializeAsV3(serializer);
        var json = writer.ToString(); // this is the openapi document
        
        // serve it as json
        context.Response.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Application.Json;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried but it still loads the default swagger index.html.

Comment: Did you make changes in `Swagger_Custom_index.html`

Comment: I tried! U have just copy and paste the code from GitHub. When I browse `https://localhost:44397/docs` it redirects to `https://localhost:44397/docs/index.html` and loads the default index.html

Comment: oh yeah, it loads. But how would I edit the UI that is rendered in the `<div id="swagger-ui"></div>`?

Comment: You can modify the UI with CSS as much as possible. For other things, you need to build your own swagger.js: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/

Comment: If you need to customize the behavior, you can write your own plugins without rebuilding swagger ui.

Comment: By any chance do you know how can I access the `/docs/v1/docs.json` programmatically? 
I tried by this approach but it didn't work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499188/timeout-error-in-trying-to-access-swagger-json-in-ihostedservice-through-a-httpc

Comment: Sure, let me prepare an answer

Comment: @aakash Can you open a new question? That question is not related to this one, it'd be better if it stands on its own.

Comment: That is my own question, you can answer on that. Which explains how I tried

Comment: I mean that generating openapi doc is not related to serving custom HTML

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499188/timeout-error-in-trying-to-access-swagger-json-in-ihostedservice-through-a-httpc

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I'll post the answer there.